# How to make scaled arrows for flowcharts?

Tags: corel-draw, information-graphics, adobe-draw

I am not sure if this is a right place to ask my[image] question.

I need to make multiple flow charts with scaled arrows. For instance, (refer figure) A is any material and it is

- Converted into B and C in process 1
- Converted into D and E in process 2

Conversion of A to B,C,D and E is marked with arrows 1,2,3 and 4, respectively.

let say,

Conversion of A to B - 1   units
Conversion of A to C - 4.3 units
Conversion of A to D - 7.5 units
Conversion of A to E - 10  units

Now, I need to scale the thickness of the arrows between 1 and 10 in both flowcharts with arrow 1 (A to B) being the thinnest and 4 arrow (A to E) being the thickest.

What software I can use to draw such scaled arrows?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Please let me know for other information.

Thanks and regards,
Ram

Comment: Obviously you already have tried different stroke widths for the arrows and didn't like the result (=also bigger arrowheads vertically and horizontally). Can you provide some sketch of the wanted result?

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator can adjust stroke and arrowheads of **Lines**.

Draw your lines with the line tool or the pen tool. Edit the stroke individually, or if there is a group of lines that need the same thickness then group them together and they can be worked on as one.

With your line selected open the stroke window. The arrowhead options are visible. The arrowheads in your example above look like option #7 Set your arrowhead at the correct end of the line. Adjust size with the scale tool here, or with the stroke thickness setting.

Clarification: set line thickness and arrowhead size with the stroke weight. If the thickness is right but the arrowhead is the wrong size the adjust it with the arrowhead scale tool.

Once your arrows are set and grouped you can scale them with "scale strokes and effects" and their look will stay the same. Likewise with your arrow settings in memory you can draw new lines and they will be like your arrows.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions. This is very important for me at this moment. I will try them and let you know the out come! Thanks again for helping me out in a crucial moment.

Answer (score 0):

In Corel-draw you can use set values by arithmetic operations. In outline menu (F12), you can set the width of any line with respect to other. For example, if line 1 width is 2 points, and you want to set line 2 width 2.5 time line 1 width, you can simply set line 2 width by putting (2*2.5) which turns out to be 5 points.